# How to set multiple paths with update-alternatives

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, java

For example, the following command install `java` to `/usr/bin/java`

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /opt/java7/bin/java 1 && update-alternatives --set java /opt/java7/bin/java
```

What if I also want to set `java` under `/bin/java` at the same time?

Comment: And what would be the reason to do this? You can install a `java` at `/bin` and call it with `/bin/java`.

Answer (score 0):

You must create new `alternative` under different name, but you shouldn't do that unless you know what are you doing, I just don't see the reason:

`PATH` variable by default will contain both `/bin/` and `/usr/bin/`. Modern systems even have symlinks for `/bin/` and `/sbin/`, targeting `/usr/bin/` and `/usr/sbin/` respectively, same with `/lib/` and `/lib64/`.